# Date Convert varchar(10)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables with dates in them, the datatype in table 1 is (datetime, null). The datatype in table 2 is varchar(10). I'm trying to write a query that will match the two dates from each table and label if they are correct or not based on a macth. I have copied the query below but I always come unstuck with the convert syntax, I'm trying to get `DD/MM/YYY`. I would appreciate anybody's help on wrapping the correct syntax around the date columns.

```
Select  TBL1.ID,
        TBL1.AccountName,
        TBL1.StartDate,
        TBL2.StartDate,              
        CASE
        WHEN LEFT(TBL1.StartDate,10) = TBL2.StartDate THEN 'Correct' ELSE 'Incorrect' END AS 'Date Check'

FROM TBL1

INNER JOIN TBL2 ON TB1.ID = TBL2.ID

GROUP BY    TBL1.ID,
    TBL1.AccountName,
    TBL1.StartDate,
    TBL2.StartDate
```

Comment: your varchar(10) date stored in which format

Comment: CONVERT(datetime,TBL1.StartDate) instead of LEFT(TBL1.StartDate,10)

Comment: you are much better off changing your varchar to a datetime for the compare.  It will show you if anything in that field is not in a valid format date.

Comment: Why do people insist on storing dates as string? STOP DOING THAT.

Comment: Believe me Aaron I've asked our DBA's to change the datatype but they won't and they won't give me the permission to change it myself.

Comment: I wouldn't call them DBAs then

Answer (score 2):

```
CONVERT(datetime,TBL1.StartDate)
```

instead of

```
LEFT(TBL1.StartDate,10)
```

Left will produce you a string but you need a datetime type to make the =.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I tried to change the LEFT to Convert and got the following:                                   Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Please try what @mhasan said: CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),TBL1.StartDate,103)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
CONVERT(varchar(10),Date,103) as StartDate
```

instead  `LEFT(TBL1.StartDate,10)`

Answer (score 1):

For correct date comparison you first need to cast varchar type to corresponding datetime representation and then convert both date dates to common format and then compare.

So change

```
LEFT(TBL1.StartDate,10) = TBL2.StartDate
```

To

```
CONVERT( varchar(11),TBL1.StartDate,101) = CONVERT(varchar(11),CAST(TBL2.StartDate as DATETIME),101)
```

Casting varchar column TBL2.StartDate to datetime will check for valid date values and throw error if invalid date value has been entered.

Also to get date columns in **dd/mm/yyyy** format use

```
Select 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),TBL1.StartDate,103),
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),TBL2.StartDate,103)
```

[More detailed format list here . I suggest bookmarking it,very helpful](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)